# What does "=>" mean in standard ml?

Tags: sml

Seems to mean a function outputs this... but I can't find it explained anywhere.
I know `->` is for types, I'm asking for `=>` to be explained.

```ml
val twice = fn f => fn x => f(f x);
```

^Example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Together with the keyword `fn` they form lambda expressions, i.e. anonymous functions. In your example, `twice` gets assigned such a lambda expression. With more obvious parantheses:

```
val twice = (fn f => (fn x => f(f x)))
```

`twice` is therefore a function that takes a function, and returns another function (another lambda expression). When you call a lambda expression, the same things happen like when you call a normal function:

```
- fun plus2 x = x + 2;
> val plus2 = fn : int -> int
- twice plus2 4
> val it = 8 : int
```

`twice plus2` means we call twice with `plus2` as the parameter f, therefore it is equivalent to `fn x => plus2(plus2 x)`. When we then call the result on 4, `x` is replaced by `4`, leading to `plus2(plus2 4)` which results in 8.

---

Function definition using `fun` can be seen as syntactic sugar for assigning lambda expressions to names, i.e. the following two lines are equivalent:

```
fun foo x = x * 3
val foo = fn x => x * 3
```